# How to tokenize phrase in Solr and get facets

Tags: solr, tokenize

I want something to tokenize the data based on the given phrases in the .txt file.
Normally the facet query gives me white space tokenized facets. But I want the result to be like this.

for e.g my data is "aaa bbb-ccc ddd eee" for the field "test_data" the facets should be like this

```
<lst name="test_data">
    <int name="aaa">1</int>
    <int name="bbb-ccc">1</int>
    <int name="ddd eee">1</int>
</lst>
```

and somefile.txt will have "bbb-ccc" & "ddd eee" as phrases

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that KeepWordFilterFactory can do the job. I added this fieldtype in the schema

```
<fieldType name="text_keepword" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeepWordFilterFactory" words="keepwords.txt" ignoreCase="false" enablePositionIncrements="false"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and this field

```
<field name="keep_fld" type="text_keepword" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build your own Tokenizer, you could use the PatternTokenizer:

> For example, you have a list of terms, delimited by a semicolon and
>   zero or more spaces: mice; kittens; dogs.

```
<fieldType name="semicolonDelimited" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=";\s*" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternTokenizerFactory

This way you can add your own regex with bbb-ccc in it.

Comment: But the pattern is not fixed. I want some fixed words/phrases to be tokenized, rest can be ignored. I ll want to specify the list in .txt file like we do in stopwords.txt for ignoring some words. I want exact opposite of it, just to including some pre-determined words.